# Using System.Security.SecureString in .NET Remoting App?

Tags: c#, .net-remoting, securestring

I am developing a Remoting application where a client looks up store specific information to login to a web server. It sets the user name and passwords in a class that stores the properties as System.Security.SecureString. I then try to pass the class with the login credentials to a server object that uses it to connect to the web host, get and some information back. When I call the server method I this error:

```
Type 'System.Security.SecureString' in Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

The class that contains the SecureStrings is marked as serializeable, and this was working while developing until I added the SecureString properties. Is there something I need to do to make this work, or am I going to have to change SecureString to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to get data from a `SecureString`, which is a good thing.  If you want to use `SecureString` you'll have to implement a custom `Serializer` on your object that can take the `SecureString` and save it as something usable (maybe even encrypting it in the process).

Comment: Don't like it, but changed all the SecureString to string and I'll just have to settle for the encryption provided by the channel

Answer (score 0):

Secure string class is not visible to COM.That`s why it is showing this error. May be converting secure string to string and then serializing it will help.